# Floating div issue in IE

Tags: jquery, html

Further to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8990246/frame-like-in-html/8990407#8990407 I implemented floating divs in my JSP. It works properly in firefox but not in IE

This is how I placed the div

```
<div id="div2">
    <font class='passageNumber'>Passage II</font>
    <font class='passageText'>
        <center>
            <font class='title'>What does Millie
                hope for?
            </font>
        </center>
<br />

TEST PASSAGE
</font>
</div>
```

The CSS i used is

```
#div2, #div3 {
    overflow: auto;
    float: left;
    height: 450px;
}




#div2{
    display:inline-block;
    width: 50%;
}

#div3 {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 50%;

}
```

U can see the allignment in the attached image [image: SCREEN SHOT]

Whereas the same works fine in firefox.

but in IE the "passage II" text comes down and if the passage is big, double scroll bar is appearning. Please help

Comment: The question you linked to has been closed. Could you possibly include some CSS that you're using to achieve this floating dilemma?

Comment: I used floating div to achieve it #div2, #div3 {
    overflow: auto;
    float: left;
    height: 450px;
}




#div2{
    width: 50%;
}

#div3 {
    width: 50%;
}

Comment: can you place the css in your question instead

Comment: Please provide us with your HTML/CSS for better answers/responses.

Comment: Which version of IE are you using to test with? I've tested your provided code in Firefox, Chrome, IE7 (quirks and standards modes), IE8 and IE9, and they all yeild good results...

Comment: Thanks Chris. It worked fine ... There were few issues in HTML and that was blocking the view properly. Now its working good :-). Thanks once again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not to do the work for you, but I'd suggest using HTML which has a better connection with current standards and trends to provide a more solid and stable solution.

I'd first construct the `div` which would contain everything that you'd float, then add the elements into that, using appropriate mark-up for those elements:

```
<div id="div2">
    <div class='heading'>Passage II</div>
    <div class='passageText'>

        <div class='title'>What does Millie hope for?</div>
        <p>TEST PASSAGE</p>

    </div>
</div>
```

...and for your CSS I might try:

```
.div2
{
    float: left;
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
}

.heading
{
    font-size: larger;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.passageText
{
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

.title
{
    text-align: center;
}
```

Just keep it neat, relevant and well constructed, and you should dodge these annoyances quite successfully - most of the time! Hope this helps...

***EDIT:***

If you have no control over the HTML, and that's the way it's just formatted, I might also try adding the `display: block;` attribute / value to the style sheet to make it behave more like a `div` element. In general, with the code you provided, block-level displaying of those elements wouldn't ruin the structure at all:

```
font
{
    display: block;
}
```

I would try and see if I could maybe neaten up that HTML though!

Comment: Chris. Thanks for writing out for me. The problem is all the font-tags comes from DB. My work is to get the HTML from DB and place it in floating div. I know that the coding is not as per standard. But thats the requirement :-( . Storing the HTML in DB and fetching it, itself is not right I know. But thats how the company was working and never wish to change too. Can you give me some solution on how to make it work in IE too please ?

Comment: So your question is actually "how to format legacy HTML from a DB so that it would work better?" ;) Interesting...see my edit...

Comment: I added display: block. Still its the same here

Comment: Please see my latest comment on your main question. Also, there seem to be errors on the page (according to your screenshot), could those be affecting the display?