# Border issue in Floating div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Further to the discussion in [Floating div issue in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8998893/floating-div-issue-in-ie/8998981#8998981) i added Floating div in my JSP

Now I need to add a ruler-type of thick border only to my right of the "PassageDiv". CSS given below

```
#passageDiv, #questionDiv {
    overflow: auto;
    float: left;
    height: 550px;
}

#passageDiv{
    width: 50%;
}


#questionDiv {
    width: 50%;
}
```

Kind of seperator between PassageDiv and QuestionDiv am expecting. So I added below line in passageDiv

```
border: 1px solid;
```

But adding this makes my questionDiv to appear below passageDiv rather than appearing side-by-side with an seperator in middle.

Comment: Can you set a JSFiddle up as an example please?

Comment: I think the two elements dont fit in the container space because their size is: 50% + 50% + 1px(border) . Even with no border 50%+50% can be larger than 100% because of integer conversion(ex: 551px/2 -> ~226px).

You can either set negative margins, or position your elements absolutely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`border` will add border all around, just make use of `border-right` try this

```
#passageDiv{
  border-right: 2px solid black;
}
```

also decrease the `width` `percentage` a little to occupy `border`

```
#passageDiv{
    width: 48%;
}

#questionDiv {
    width: 48%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kQMVJ/)**, I'm not face issue like that,

```
#passageDiv, #questionDiv {
    overflow: auto;
    float: left;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50%;
}

#passageDiv {
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

Comment: Try some manupulation in the fiddle to get your right answer, ar just drop me a comment.

Comment: @Arun I have given the same answer 1st and 3 minutes earlier so logically my answer should be marked as accepted. isn't that unfair ??? lollzzzzz.