# Multiple FLOAT DIV and BORDER

Tags: html, css-float, border, css

I've got an issue when i try to put **2 divs, both them them floating to the left side**, **one with width 80% and the other the 20%**. Then i'd like to draw a **border on the right side of the first div** and a **box-shadow of 5px**, because each div has a different color.

So I've just searched on this site and **i've found this solution**: 
[Border issue in Floating div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9000142/border-issue-in-floating-div)

But **it's bad idea IMHO**.... i've a resolution of 1920px width and i can't put 48% for the width of a DIV.... **for 4px border i'll got a white space in the webpage for the 2% - 2px**. 
You could say, just add the background color to the body: i could because each DIV  has already it's own, but **it's also a problem OF SPACE, PROPORTIONS**!!!

**Another problem** i'm experiencing with: i've set the height 100% (on the second div, 20% width)and it works in the example; but in the real website, which is the height also set to 100% the DIV doesn't occupy the whole height of the column but just until the margin limit of the last image.

**The last problem**: box-shadow with floating div it's bad idea... 
should i put the box-shadow on the last div, just for the left side, instead of the right side for the previous div?

Look at **my code here** http://jsfiddle.net/9gp6J/

```
div#contenuto_body{
    margin: 0 0;
    padding: 0 0;
    float: left;
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;

    background-color: #C90;

    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 1px #333;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 1px #333;
    -ms-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 1px #333;   
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 1px #333;

    border-right: 4px solid #E6B800;
}

body{
    margin: 0 0;
    padding: 0 0;
}

div#ads{
    margin: 0 0;
    padding: 0 0;
    width: 20%;  
    float: left;
    height: 100%;

    background-color: #CCC;
}

div#ads img{
    width: 70%;
    max-width: 200px;
    display: block;
    margin: 25% auto;
}
```

Comment: the wording is very hard to understand but I think I know what you want...

Answer (score 0):

You could use the css3 feature `calc(...)` available in css3 depending on which browsers you are supporting this may suitable. Anything below IE9 doesn't support this so keep that in mind. Here's a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/9gp6J/9/

Any other solution would have to involve negative margins such as:

```
div#contenuto_body{
    ...
    margin-right: -4;
}
```

That should work anything IE7 and up.

Comment: Yes it works properly, so the 1 div is next to the other but the border isn't still visible

Comment: Ok i've found a great selector, and it works perfectly for the border, that's what i was looking for. **BOX-SIZING: border-box;** 
**Check it here**
http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/
**But Box-shadow is still a problem........**

Comment: just use float the other right and take off more from calc. I updated the jfiddle link

Answer (score 0):

for the border issue add a div inside the left div and give a right border to that inner div. This way the outer left div can remain 80% without the added 4px border problem.

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left">
        <div id="inner_left">
            content left
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
        content right
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div#container {
    height:200px;
}

div#left {
    float:left;
    width:80%;
    height:100%;
    background:red;
}

div#inner_left {
    border-right:4px solid black;
    height:100%;
}

div#right {
    float:left;
    width:20%;
    height:100%;
    background:green;
}
```

Check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/23CkT/1/)

Comment: mmh this works because you've set the same height for both DIVs.... try to have different heights for the DIVs, so you have to set the height to 100% and that code doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Ok i've found a great selector, and it works perfectly for the border, that's what i was looking for. **BOX-SIZING: border-box;** 
**Check it here**
http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/
**But Box-shadow is still a problem........**

Comment: If you set the left and right heights to 100% you must have some containing div with a preset height. 100% height only works when the containing element's height is known. I have updated my answer.